# Pushing certain files from home directory to git repo to make setting up new boxes easier

Tags: git, github, configuration, config, customization

I keep certain files from my home directory in a git repo in order to make it easier to set up new boxes or recover from mangled home directories or goofs in editing, etc. It's mainly stuff like .bashrc, .emacs, .tmux, etc., and my personal ~/bin directory of custom utilities I use a lot. It helps a lot because at any time I may edit these files on any of these boxes, and need those changes to propagate to all my other boxes. Git merge makes all that a breeze.

I also like to push my .ssh directory, that's the biggest pain in the ass to copy from box to box. (Of course, I encrypt any private key files I have in there which necessitates I always have to use ssh-agent, enter passwords, etc, to initially load the keys but it's worth it. Using ssh on a multi-user box is inherently dangerous. I hope the ssh-agent setup protects my private keys in these situations, does it? Is there a better way? Store keys on a thumb drive? What if I lose the thumb drive or it gets corrupted? I would be screwed).

Wondering if anyone else does this, what dangers are there I haven't considered, and that maybe this is actually a good way to do it.

Here's one problem I have. I work on Mac, Linux, and Windows (I use Cygwin, shut up, I know) boxes. Obviously, I can't use the same executables (my ~/bin directory) and often even the shell scripts are incompatible. For example, the Mac OS "find" command is really weak, doesn't have many of the important options the Linux version has. So a lot of my custom shell scripts that use find don't work right.

Is this going to require multiple "master" branches, one for each OS? That's what I do now and they start to get out of sync, and merging them is dangerous.

Comment: What exactly is your question?
Regarding the different scripts per OS: did you try to detect the current OS in your scripts and only execute the appropriate commands/parameters then?

Comment: Just feedback on any dangers or suggestions. There are quite a few questions in there. I don't want to ask specifically, "How do I detect OS". I can do that, I want to know if there's an easier way to do any of what I covered in that setup I use.

Answer (score 1):

Many people have dotfiles that they share across systems, so a lot of these problems are well understood.

As far as the portability of scripts, I generally just accept that on macOS, the standard utilities are less functional and I write code that works across systems, as inconvenient as that may be.  Similarly, I use `ps` options instead of poking around in the `/proc` file system, since macOS doesn't have those options.  When possible, I prefer to look at the POSIX spec and write my scripts with only those options in mind, or write them in a non-shell language.  Sometimes I will use nonportable shell functionality if I know it's part of all of GNU coreutils, macOS, and the major BSD variants.

When I write a shell script, I target a [Debian `/bin/sh`](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-files.html#scripts): that is, mostly POSIX, with a few extensions.  That means it will work on pretty much any Unix system as long as it isn't using AT&T ksh for `/bin/sh` (since that lacks `local`).

I use zsh and I autoload functions that abstract various parts of my shell configuration so they work on various systems.  If I need nonportable functionality like `stat(1)` in my shell, there's often a zsh builtin that works instead.

I keep one main branch for dotfiles and a side branch with different configuration for work.  All my changes that aren't a work-specific customization go into the main branch, even if the changes are only relevant for work, and the side branch gets rebased on top of it.  For example, I only ever use a Mac at work, but all versions of my dotfiles will work on macOS.

I don't check binaries into my repository.  I build any custom binaries on each system; you may like to have them as submodules if need be, or have a shell script in your `~/bin` directory that installs the correct versions of the necessary packages (depending on system) and then builds your tools.

Similarly, I don't check in any SSH keys.  The encryption used for PEM private keys is pretty bad if you need it to work across platforms and doesn't include integrity protection.  Every system gets its own private keys and I have a script to deploy updates to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to all affected machines.  If you're using GitHub, you can actually upload all your public keys to GitHub and then fetch the following public URL as you need to: `https://github.com/<username>.keys`.

Comment: Great suggestions. Thanks. While reading your list it dawned on me that I can just create separate subdirs for executables of each OS, like ~/bin/macos, ~/bin/linux and ~/bin/windows but generic shell scripts that work cross-platform I can just keep in ~/bin. Although your idea about just having the install script for the utilities for each OS is good too. Windows is kind of lame in that regard though as there's no generic command line installation utility. Every executable needs it's own install program :(

Comment: I use Chocolatey if I need to install Windows tooling, but I will admit that I'm not a frequent Windows user.  Winget may also be a viable choice.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding dotfiles, I prefer using [`knoebber/dotfile`](https://github.com/knoebber/dotfile) to version them (one repo per platform)

And I would not export/copy private keys across platforms, but keep them where they are, with one private key per OS.